# What is difference between escape sequences and string operator?

Tags: php, html

What is difference between escape sequences and string operator except for regular expressions?

Below is my test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $a = "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\" onclick=\"alert(1)\">Im Google</a>";
    $b = "<a href="."http://www.google.com"." onclick="."alert(2)>Im Google, too</a>";
    echo "$a<br>$b";
    ?>
</body>
```

Result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMrdf.png)

More result:

[Two href of the a elements has double quotes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88Vuo.png)

Comment: Concatenating costs more I guess.

Comment: What does the result look like? It's not identical, if you expect that...

Comment: Also `http://www.google.com` will not have quotes the way you're applying on the second option. You can use single quotes and add quotes inside of it, or do the reverse.

Comment: I like how you make that sound like it's just a side detail rather than the actual difference, @Phiter Fernandes.

Comment: Yeah I know the actual difference is huge, I'm just commenting.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes No, It has double quotes like first code.

Comment: @chlusher *1 character more than the other*. Remove the `, too` and you'll see; it's just one character difference.

Comment: @chlusher No, it does not. Don't look at it through your *DOM inspector*, look at the **raw source.** The DOM inspector gives you a reconstructed, normalised representation of the current DOM tree, not your original source.

Comment: @Fred-ii- that's rather inaccurate to say, if the URL was different the results would be differently in action, see my comment on the below answer.

Comment: @deceze You are right.

Comment: @Prix *Poh-tay-toe, poh-tah-toe*. Escaping double quotes renders proper HTML markup. If you were to copy OP's code and gotten rid of the extra `, too`, you'll see there's only 1 character difference than the other, so there's no real "speed" gain, or any gain for that matter really. I always use proper HTML markup in PHP.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you're not paying closer attention to the differences in $a and $b.

Comment: I'm sorry for I didn't know difference of the developer tool and raw source.

Comment: @Fred-ii- [clearly not :) but feel free to disagree](https://eval.in/551214). Keep in mind that we are talking about how the PHP prints it and not whether today's browse are able to understand and render the HTML properly even if printed wrongly.

Comment: @Fred-ii- [Just to further improve my point, here is a JSFiddle example of what I meant as to why your assumption is wrong](https://jsfiddle.net/1g4sa0ds/) see the 3rd link. `If you were to copy OP's code and gotten rid of the extra , too, you'll see there's only 1 character difference than the other, so there's no real "speed" gain, or any gain for that matter really.` so by your logic the 3rd link should have worked but its clearly missing part of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's look at the result:

```
$a = "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\" onclick=\"alert(1)\">Im Google</a>";
```

is:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="alert(1)">Im Google</a>
```

while this:

```
$b = "<a href="."http://www.google.com"." onclick="."alert(2)>Im Google, too</a>";
```

is:

```
<a href=http://www.google.com onclick=alert(2)>Im Google, too</a>
```

Apples and oranges.

Both happen to have the same meaning in HTML, since none of the arguments contain spaces. But if they did, you'd have noticed the difference yourself very quickly.

Comment: I just want to know that any difference between two things.

Comment: Not to mention if the URL had a space it would break the URL and perhaps even the html code depending on what the URL was. For example: `$b = "<a href="."http://yoursite.com/some link/".">test</a>";` In this case your link would become `http://yoursite.com/some` instead of `http://yoursite.com/some link/`

Comment: @chlusher One escapes a special character, and the other concatenates two strings. I'm at a loss for what you want to hear, to be quite honest.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash `\` is used in "string context" to escape some characters to either have the same character inside the string which the string is encapsulated with, or to insert some special character, like a new-line `\n`.

There is a difference between "embedded code" and "regular expressions":

- the source-code you provided is PHP code embedded in HTML
- regular expressions ("regex") implies some logic that can be defined in a string like this: `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}$` and the "special characters" inside it can also be "escaped" with the backslash, including the backslash itself - (with another backslash) - same as "normal" strings.

You can escape your quotes the way you did - as the first example (a), but that makes your code more complex. You can simply use the double, or single quotes as needed like this:

- "Monica's attractive... car"
- 'Sandy says: "Hi!"'

Remember to use "curly braces" `{ }` when embedding variables inside a double-quoted string context like this:

```
$foo = 'bar';
echo "I like Cadbury's lunch-{$foo}";
```

### Edit

As pointed out in the comments:

The "curly braces" reference is just good practice as it prevents nasty surprises when using variables directly before some alpha-numeric characters, which if left out you may get an "E_NOTICE" error, or you will have to resort to concatenation.

Comment: On that last point: *why?* :) Curly braces aren't *needed* per se to interpolate values...

Comment: @deceze :: It's good practice as it prevents some characters that interfere with your variable names, like i.e: "{$foo}bells", where `$foo='bar'` so that will be "barbells"; however, if you skip the `{ }` you may get a notice about variable "foobells" being undefined; or you have to split up the string and use concatenation methods.. so, just good practice I guess ;)

Comment: Fair enough, but that distinction is important IMO. Don't blindly prescribe it, point out the *why*. Personally I forgo the braces *unless and until they're necessary* for disambiguation.